# "needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.": What security check is that?

Tags: internet, cloudflare

From time to time, when browsing a website I see the following message:

> [Webpage URL] needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.

[image]

What kind of security check on my connection are they doing?

I've seen this message on Chrome, Opera and Firefox. The screenshot above was taken on https://chat.openai.com/chat

Comment: They are most likely making sure you are not a part of a botnet or something similar. Exactly what they are checking is going to be a secret to ensure people can't evade their checks easily.

Comment: The bottom of the page showed that the check was from Cloudflare.